# Can I use a stored procedure from one server on another with entity framework (asp.net mvc)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am writing an application which connects to multiple servers and queries their settings and inventory information to store in a database on another server.  The number of servers is dynamically changing, but the server that the database information remains on is constant.

I haven't yet figured out how to create a dynamic connection using Entity Framework, but that is another question (although it would be nice to know if that is possible...).  For obvious security reasons, they look down upon using raw sql strings in code to query a server and would prefer that any queries are done in the form of stored procedures.

Once I begin this and maintain a connection between the two servers, I will need to query the server that I have dynamically connected to using a stored procedure that is on the server where the information will be stored.

Is there a way to do this? Or are stored procedures limited to the server that they are placed upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linked Server will work. For more information check out this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: This looks like a security nightmare.  Linking multiple servers to a single server?  Additionally, these servers are dynamic, changing.  I don't want to setup a linked server everytime a new one is added, I just want to add one to the list, ask the user for credentials, then pull the info by connecting to the server.

Comment: An alternative is to set up connections to each server dynamically via your application but with this you would have to manage connection strings which could be more complex than the linked servers.  Note that you have multiple ways to set up the Linked Server credentials which can help mitigate security issues.

Comment: That sounds like how I think I would want to do things.  Thanks for your input!  I'll probably end up managing connection strings.  Would this still allow me to use stored procedures from one server on another?  Or is this only achievable through linked servers?

Comment: In your app, it sound like you have one MAIN connection and many variable connections.  If this is the case, set up two connection objects; one for the MAIN and the other for your varying connections. Then integrate some business logic to pull the varying connection strings from your MAIN database.  When on a varying connection, the stored procedure must reside in the connected database, not the MAIN database.   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!